# How to globally disable `shell-dirtrack-mode` after `(require 'shell)`

Tags: shell-mode

`(require 'shell)` enables `shell-dirtrack-mode` globally in every buffer.  Is there a way to disable that behavior?

The only workaround that I have found is to call `(shell-dirtrack-mode -1)` for each major mode that loads (e.g., via a major-mode hook); and, for `fundamental-mode`, I created a new function that calls the same thing immediately after calling `kill-all-local-variables`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PythonNut -- in general, I prefer that my buffers have only what is needed (without anything extra).  This is especially true when I am troubleshooting / bug-fixing / developing a major or minor mode.  While many people might be able to tell themselves -- "don't worry about `shell-dirtrack-mode`, be happy" -- I prefer that it not be there in the first instance.  I am obsessive compulsive in that regard.  One of the main reasons that I love Emacs and have invested so much time customizing it, is because almost everything is customizable -- I feel in control (colors / shapes / behavior / etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shell-dirtrack-mode` is an alias to `shell-dirtrackp`. The `shell-dirtrackp` is initialized with the value of `t` in `shell.el`.

So this variable and thus the minor mode `shell-dirtrack-mode` gets a global value of `t`. So this mode state is always on in a fresh buffer unless you actively disable it.

The solution is to change the default value of the `shell-dirtrackp` variable after it is initialized in `shell.el`:

```el
(require 'shell)
(setq-default shell-dirtrackp nil)
```

#### References

- [Default Value](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Value.html) - `setq-default`

Comment: After turning off `global-shell-dirtrack-mode`, the creation of new buffers still default to `shell-dirtrack-mode` being enabled -- e.g., `(get-buffer-create "*foo*")` will have `shell-dirtrack-mode` active in buffer `*foo*` even though `(global-shell-dirtrack-mode -1)` was previously evaluated.

Comment: Hmm, you will have to edebug to figure out what is calling `shell-dirtrack-mode`. Above is a solution to only disable that mode globally in all the buffers. It does not prevent that mode from getting enabled again. Probably some hook is re-enabling this mode.

Comment: After some digging out, the `kill-all-local-variables` function is the one that resets the state of `shell-dirtrack-mode`. That function is implemented in `src/buffer.c`. But looks like the local var reset is the cause of this..

Comment: @lawlist Phew, that was hell of a debug. Try out this updated solution now. It boiled down to modifying the default value of the local variable (minor mode var) and disabling the minor mode globally. After that, the mode stays off even after creating new buffers.

Comment: Based on your hard work, I see that just `(require 'shell) (setq-default shell-dirtrackp nil)` resolves the issue.  There is no need to create a global mode.  This will also suffice:  `(require 'shell) (setq-default shell-dirtrack-mode nil)`

Comment: Strange.. I tried doing just that and that didn't work.  But may be because I had a lot of modified base functions to debug this and also because I was playing with the state of `permanent-local` property.

Comment: It only works if `(require 'shell)` precedes `(setq-default . . .)`

Comment: Alright, I can confirm what you said in a fresh emacs session. Will update my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much -- that sure was an interesting method that the `shell.el` author came up with for creating a global minor mode -- your help is greatly appreciated!  :)